# How to create a boxplot by grouping by Month and year with more than one years of data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am unable to recreate the error with sample data and I cannot upload all my data. But I have shown what my chart looks like. From this chart ggplot looks to be reading every date it's own band. Why?

[image]

The code to generate the chart is:

```
 ggplot(data=tEN, aes(factor(Date_MMMYYYY), Amount))  + 
    geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE)
```

Here is a sample of what my data looks like. The only difference is I have a few more columns.

```
Dates<-c("Dec-02-2015", "Dec-03-2015", "Dec-04-2015", "Dec-05-2015", "Dec-06-2015", "Dec-07-2015", "Dec-08-2015", "Dec-09-2015", "Dec-10-2015", "Dec-11-2015", "Dec-12-2015", "Dec-13-2015", "Dec-14-2015", "Dec-15-2015", "Dec-16-2015", "Dec-17-2015","Oct-01-2015", "Oct-02-2015", "Oct-03-2015", "Oct-04-2015", "Oct-05-2015", "Oct-06-2015", "Oct-07-2015", "Oct-08-2015", "Oct-09-2015", "Oct-10-2015", "Oct-11-2015", "Oct-12-2015", "Oct-13-2015", "Oct-14-2015", "Oct-15-2015", "Oct-16-2015")
x<-rnorm(length(Dates),0,1)
df <- data.frame(Dates, x)
df$Dates_MMMYYYY<-format(as.Date(df$Dates,"%b-%d-%Y"),"%b-%Y")
ggplot(data=df, aes(factor(Dates_MMMYYYY), x))  + 
    geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE)
```

Any idea why the boxplot is not working?

Comment: amount is probably not a numeric value which it should if you want a boxplot

Answer (score 1):

You can create month-year groupings to feed to ggplot:

```
library(lubridate)

# Convert Dates to date format
df$Dates = mdy(df$Dates)

# Create a month-year grouping variable
df$monthYear = paste0(month(df$Dates, label=TRUE),"-",year(df$Dates))

# Order the levels of the month-year grouping variable
# I've created three years worth here. Adjust as needed for the range of your data.
df$monthYear = factor(df$monthYear, levels=paste0(month.abb,"-", rep(2014:2016,each=12)))

ggplot(data=df, aes(monthYear, x))  + 
  geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE)
```

You can also create month breaks on the fly using the `cut` function:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(cut(Dates, breaks="month"), x))  + 
  geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE)
```